# A string replace problem

Tags: php, replace

```
$string = '1.this is the first2.second3.and thethird';
$string = str_replace('??', '<br> ??', $string);
echo $string; 
//output: 
1.this is the first <br>
2.second <br>
3.and thethird
```

What str_replace do i need?
please note that the frist number on output has no `<br>` tag.
thanks

Comment: You need [preg_replace](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat scratch.php
<?php
$string = '1.this is the first2.second3.and thethird';
$string = preg_replace('/([^0-9])([0-9]+\.)/', "\$1 <br>\n\$2", $string);
echo $string; 



$ php scratch.php | more
1.this is the first <br>
2.second <br>
3.and thethird



$
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how much control you have over the input string, but using explode() is a lot easier and cleaner.  The only requirement is you need to be able to put delimiters in your string.

```
$string = '1.this is the first|2.second|3.and thethird';
$array=explode('|',$string);
foreach($line as $array){
   echo $line."<br>";
}
```

Comment: what is wrong with this solution? it is very simple and effective